# Simulate Click and Drag in OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, mouse, hid

I am trying to simulate mouse action via programming.

I am not able to do **click and drag action** reliably.

For click and drag I am doing the following actions in the order mentioned below

1. Post left mouse button pressed event at current mouse pointer position (only once)
2. Move the mouse (as mouse down event is already sent, it must act as mouse down and drag, selecting text from the initial mouse postion)
3. Post left mouse button release event to end mouse hold action.

In apple applications such as Xcode, or Safari, this method does not work reliably (It docent highlight text when dragged, but with actual mouse I can highlight text by click and drag). Cannot drag icons either.

However in **Firefox**, this technique works. The selection follows mouse! That is as we move mouse pointer, the selection also changes accordingly, which is what I need.

The following is the code I use to send mouse tap events.

```
-(void)_sendMouseEvent:(int)mouseEvent withMouseButton:(CGMouseButton)mouseBtn
{
    CGEventRef ourEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    NSPoint mouseLoc  = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent); //get current mouse position

    CGEventRef mouseClick = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
                                                    NULL,
                                                    mouseEvent,
                                                    mouseLoc,
                                                    mouseBtn
                                                    );
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, mouseClick);
    CFRelease(ourEvent);
    CFRelease(mouseClick);
}
```

I did try sending mouse down events at regular intervals, but it made no change.

Do you have any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Please suggest any workarounds that come to your mind.

Comment: `CGPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];` is tidier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that we need to send mouse event `kCGEventLeftMouseDragged` first, to start dragging and selecting.

```
[self _sendMouseEvent:kCGEventLeftMouseDragged withMouseButton:kCGMouseButtonLeft]; //Start draging.

-(void)_sendMouseEvent:(int)mouseEvent withMouseButton:(CGMouseButton)mouseBtn
{
    CGEventRef ourEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    NSPoint mouseLoc  = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent); //get current mouse position

    CGEventRef mouseClick = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
                                                    NULL,
                                                    mouseEvent,
                                                    mouseLoc,
                                                    mouseBtn
                                                    );
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, mouseClick);
    CFRelease(ourEvent);
    CFRelease(mouseClick);
}
```

Comment: how you implement this exactly, I mean what location you pass into mouseLoc? just current position it doesn't drag anywhere

Comment: There is a real mouse attached, and only thing this code does is that it stimulates the button press, and initiates the drag event `kCGEventLeftMouseDragged`. So after sending the dragged and button press events, **the pointer is moved by actual mouse**. As the mouse moves after sending the events, the selected object is moved to the current pointer position or selects the text (click and drag action). Once the dragging ends, the button release event, and dragging stopped events are posted.

Comment: so I need to send >=3 events: kCGEventLeftMouseDown (start_x, start_y),  n x kCGEventLeftMouseDragged (i<=n, end_i_x, end_ i_y), kCGEventLeftMouseUp (end_n_x, end_n_y) . I wrote this and this works but I need to sleep between mouse_down, mouse_drag, mouse_drag, mouse_up at least 10 ms! If I don't sleep it doesn't work correctly. Why?

Comment: A delay between posting each event IS the key to making this work. In my experience, usleep(200000) works well on a 2018 2.9Ghz 15" rMBP. Older hardware may need a longer delay.

Comment: I ran into similar issues (like my dragging being especially wonky in Xcode) until I realized you are supposed to either send `.mouseMoved` OR `.leftMouseDragged`—NOT both—during the drag. So ensure this order: `1x .leftMouseDown`,  `N+ .leftMouseDragged`, `1x .leftMouseUp`. In other words, a simple `isDragging = Bool` can get this working. Phew, that stumped me for hours.